# How to mass install applications to clients remotely

Tags: installation, remote-access

I work for a company with 500 retail shops all over the country. Each shop is provided with 2 or 3 PCs.

Is there a way to mass install applications, without having to access one PC at a time (e.g. via VNC)?

Comment: What operating system(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of different answers to this. I work for a large organisation with thousands of clients to update. There are a number of different frameworks and toolsets to use (Landesk, Tivoli). Other tools I can think of are Microsoft Systems Center (assuming the clients are Windows).

All the tools usually involve being able to write a silent install for the software in question and using the tools to execute it on every client.

If the clients are connected to an Active Directory and are Windows, you could use that to deploy via login scripts. Alternatively you could probably cobble something together with psexec and go through a file to map a drive, copy an install script to the client, run the install on a share that is accesible to all clients, then execute it. Then iterate on to the next client.